# How can I use BungeeCord Message Channel on Velocity?

Tags: velocity, bungeecord, spigot

I try to use the BungeeCord Message Channel on Velocity.

I know this work. Here is my code:

```
player.sendMessage("§aWait...");
ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
out.writeUTF("Connect");
out.writeUTF("Lobby2");

player.sendPluginMessage(plugin, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
```

This code works, if I use BungeeCord as my proxy. But not if I use Velocity.

Comment: Are you sure "Lobby2" is on the velocity proxy that you are actually logged on ? because this should do the trick

Comment: Yes the Server Lobby2 in connect with the velocity proxy. If you mean this. I have the same configuration also on waterfall and there works. And: if I enter the command '/server Lobby2' ingame I connect to the Lobby2 Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since more recent Minecraft versions, it is recommended to use the `bungeecord:main` channel (though Velocity should support both just fine).

Also, it is important to make sure that you use a Velocity version newer than v1.1.0 ([as seen here](https://github.com/PaperMC/Velocity/issues/68#issuecomment-558826904)).

Another thing, though it should not be necessary (and probably won't change anything for this issue), it's recommended to also [enable velocity-support](https://docs.velocitypowered.com/en/latest/users/player-info-forwarding.html#paper).

If you remain having this issue, it might be best to create an issue on the [Velocity Github repository](https://github.com/PaperMC/Velocity/issues), so they may be able to help you further!

Comment: Sorry but if I execute the command I get this exception: org.bukkit.plugin.messaging.ChannelNotRegisteredException: Attempted to send a plugin message through the unregistered channel `bungeecord:main'.

Comment: Make sure to register the channel onEnable like so: getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "bungeecord:main");